# Reading sqlite3 file without using libraries C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In my project I need to minimize the number of external libraries used and I decided to make my own small sqlite3 file reader. I only need to read the file, without writing or saving. If you have any ideas or information on this matter, I will be glad to listen to you.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information.

Comment: I'm almost sure that you don't want to write your own driver for SQLite. It's more complicated that you may think.

Comment: _" I need to minimize the number of external libraries used"_ Minimize doesn't mean "get rid of all". This may be good for some libraries that are more of a convenience but I wouldn't recommend doing this with SQLite. Pick and choose your battles. Writing a readonly SQLite driver is not one you're likely to win without sinking **a lot** of development time in to.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.